# Useing filtering bucket to filter a moving average result

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I do need to know if I can filter based on my moving average results? ( I just want the ones that are = 100 ) I try to use filtering bucket but always receive an error

"Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [hostname_bucket_filter]."

Do not know what else to do, this is the query:

```
"aggs":{
    "aggs_host":{
      "terms":{
        "field":"dimensions.hostname.value",
        "size":10,
        "order":{"_key":"desc"},
        "min_doc_count":1},
        "aggs":{
          "aggs_fs":{
            "terms":{
              "field":"dimensions.mount.value",
              "size":10,
              "order":{"_key":"desc"},
              "min_doc_count":1
              
            },
              "aggs":{
                "agg_date":{
                  "date_histogram":{
                    "interval":"1h",
                    "field":"timestamp",
                    "min_doc_count":0
                    
                  },
                  
                  "aggs":{
                    "agg_ave":{
                      "avg":{
                        "field":"value.double"
                        
                      }
                      
                    },
                    "aggs_ma":{
                      "moving_avg":{
                        "buckets_path":"agg_ave",
                        "window":6,
                        "model":"holt_winters",
                        "settings" : {
                          "type": "mult",
                          "alpha": 0.6,
                          "beta": 0.8,
                          "gamma": 0.6,
                          "period" : 3
                        },
                        "predict":7,
                        "minimize":false
                      }
                      
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
          }
        }
    }
  },
  "hostname_bucket_filter" : {
    "bucket_selector" : {
      "bucket_path" : {
        "the_hosts_filt": "aggs_host>aggs_fs>agg_date>agg_ave.aggs_ma"
        
      },
      "script" : "params.the_hosts_filt >= 100"
      
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: `hostname_bucket_filter` is outside of `aggs`, hence not recognized by the query parser, it should be somewhere inside that section. It helps to properly format your JSON ;-)

Comment: I tried to put also inside, but nothing seems to works, do you have any example where you have used with moving average?

Comment: hmmm, actually `moving_avg` and `bucket_selector` are both pipeline aggregations (they run on all buckets after all buckets/metrics aggregations have run) and I don't think you can combine them, it's either/or